# Python 3.3 GUI Program

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.3

Celsius to Fahrenheit-- Write a GUI program that converts Celsius temperatures to Fahrenheit temperatures.  The user should be able to enter a Celsius temperature, click a button, and then see the equivalent Fahrenheit temperature.  Use the following formula to make the conversion:
F = 9/5C +32
F is the Fahrenheit temperature and C is the Celsius temperature.

THIS IS THE CODE I HAVE SO FAR, THE ERROR I GET says "invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''" I need help getting it to run correctly.

```
#import
#main function
from tkinter import *
def main():
    root=Tk()

    root.title("Some GUI")
    root.geometry("400x700")
    #someothersting=""
    someotherstring=""
#enter Celcius
    L1=Label(root,text="Enter a Celcius temperature.")
    E1=Entry(root,textvariable=someotherstring)
    somebutton=Button(root, text="Total", command=convert(someotherstring))

    somebutton.pack()
    E1.pack()
    L1.pack()
    root.mainloop()#main loop


#convert Celcius to Fahrenheit
def convert(somestring):
    thestring=""
    thestring=somestring
    cel=0
    far=0
    cel=int(thestring)
    far=(9/5*(cel))+32
    print(far)
```

Comment: What are you inputting in the field for `someotherstring`, sounds like you typed in "10C" or something that `int()` can't parse.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is this line;

```
somebutton=Button(root, text="Total", command=convert(someotherstring))
```

...which will call `convert(someotherstring)` immediately and assign the result to command. Since someotherstring is empty when this line is reached, it will fail to convert the value and fail the program.

If you don't want it evaluated immediately but instead on button press, you can use a lambda as a command;

```
somebutton=Button(root, text="Total", command=lambda: convert(E1.get()))
```

...which will eliminate the use of `someotherstring` completely and just call convert with the contents of `E1` when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to `int("")`

In main(), do

```
def main():
    # ...
    someotherstring = 0 # Since its trying to get int
```

Or you can check if its empty in `convert()`:

```
def convert(somestring):
    if somestring != "":    
        # cel=0 dont need these in python
        # far=0
        cel=int(somestring)
        far=(9/5*(cel))+32
        print(far)
```

**Note:** Check if you are using `someotherstring` properly with `Entry` widget. I believe you are supposed to use `StringVar()` and do `stringvar.get()` to get the text inside widget.

Comment: this is only part of the problem. The other part of the problem is how convert is bound to the button.

Comment: @BryanOakley Agree. I completely missed that